# You can't be nice and be a rock star at the same time

Tags: coordination, coordination-of-unlikes

Which of the following sentences are correct?

> 1. You can't be nice and be a rock star at the same time.
> 2. You can't be nice and a rock star at the same time.
> 3. You can't be a rock star and be nice at the same time.
> 4. You can't be a rock star and nice at the same time.

1 and 3 sound better to me. 4 looks like wrong to me. And I am not sure about 2. What do you think?

Comment: The reason #2 and #4 are both (equivalently) "awkward" is because they effectively [zeugmas](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/zeugma). If you are *nice*, that's an ***adjectival*** reference, but if you're a *rock star* you're equating one noun *(**you**)* with another noun (cf *I have three dollars and influenza, I am FumbleFingers and in a hurry...*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @Chemomechanics: Like I said, I was in a hurry! :) At the time I was pretty certain there would be at least one earlier ELU question on this issue. But if I can't find one today and no-one else posts an answer here, I'll follow up on your suggestion.